# How to avoid needing //@ts-ignore on assignments to custom window fields in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

The TypeScript compiler (and Visual Studio by extension) by default show errors for code that assign to custom `Window` fields like this:

```
window.inv = inv;
window.NPC = NPC;
```

I know that the `window` object doesn't have such fields by default as `inv` or `NPC`. Using `ts-ignore` or `ts-expect-error` comments for every line of such code seems pretty wrong. Is there a nice way to remove that kind of errors from diplaying, without touching any other ts-check functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Add a module declaration file and augment the `Window` interface using interface merging.

Here's an example:

index.ts:

```
window.foo = 42;
window.bar = "hello world";
```

index.d.ts (module declaration file):

```
interface Window {
   foo: number;
   bar: string;
}
```

You can read more about module declaration files here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html.

You can read more about interface merging here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces.